# Getting SessionFctory null using lookup

Tags: hibernate

I am getting sessionFactory null. My code is below:

```
String e = "java:/sessionfactory";
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
session = (SessionFactory) ic.lookup(e);
```

But in server log i am getting my jndi is bounded with name java:/sessionfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Add (if not added) below property in your `SessionFactory` configuration:

`<property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">hibernate.SessionFactory</property> <!-- JNDI bound Session Factory Name -->`

And then trying creating the `SessionFactory` using

```
 String e = "java:comp/env/sessionfactory";
 Context initialCntx = new InitialContext();  
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory)initialCntx.lookup(e);
```

[Here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJNDI-boundSessionFactorywithTomcat41#sthash.n2JmnhoU.dpuf) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Hibernate_Reference_Guide/J2EE_Application_Server_integration-JNDI_bound_SessionFactory.html) are good links which you can help you.

Moreover [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=927695) is a good discussion regading the same issue.

Comment: Hi Arpit whatever you told I tried but still i am getting same issue. Actually it is working fine with Ant build but recently i converted my project to maven build. And after that I am facing this issue. Could you please suggest something.

Comment: Both `Ant` and `Maven` are just build tool, they don't have any relation with JNDI, might be some other problem in code due to which `SessionFactory` is null. Can you show your code?